# Автоматическое скрытие блока при потере фокуса

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу. Есть код на js:

```
function toggle(el) {
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none';
}
```

При нажатии на

```
<li onclick = "toggle(btn)" class="input">
```

открывается блок с информацией:

```
<div id="btn" style="display: none;">
    <table id="шапка"></table>
</div>
```

Нужно как-то сделать так, что бы при потере фокуса, например при клике на любое другое поле окна блок автоматически скрывался.
К сожалению не смог найти информацию по реализации. Интересует только чистый js. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: А этот блок с информацией находится где-то в другом месте на странице или скрыт рядом с кнопкой, и играет роль всплывающей подсказки?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME добавил в вопрос. Блок идёт как чек-бокс. Нажимаем на li - открывается снизу div, нажимаем ещё раз - div закрывается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На id-то написать легко. У новичков проблемы начинаются, когда уже есть код для id, а надо переписать для классов, когда кнопок много)

`(el.style.display == "none")` — это ваше условие с первого взгляда работает, но оно немного неправильное. Фишка в том, что когда вы хотите достать `el.style.display` — оно выводит то, что реально написано в HTML-`style="..."`. Т.е. если вручную в каждый элемент не добавлять display: none, изначально будет равен `""`. Можно использовать `getComputedStyle(elem).display` чтобы получить его реальное значение.

`elem.closest('.bubu')` — если у elem есть класc .bubu - возвращает elem, а если нет - ищет этот класс у его родителя, потом у его родителя, и так до документа. И возвращает элемент с этим классом, если он найден. ( Но старые браузеры его не поддерживают → https://caniuse.com/#search=closest )

```js
var block = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

var open = document.querySelectorAll('.open');
for (var i = 0; i < open.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    open[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      // При клике на очередную кнопку - добавляем или убираем класс у блока
      block[i].classList.toggle('hidden');
    });
  })(i);
  /* можете где-то посмотреть про разницу var и let. Тут пришлось добавить (функцию)(i)
  чтобы не использовать let. С ним было бы попроще */
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('.open')) {
    return; // Если кликнули на li-переключатор - ничего не делаем.
  }
  var curr = e.target.closest('.block');
  if (curr) { // Условие выполнится только если кликнули на .block
    addClass(block, 'hidden'); // Скрываем все блоки
    curr.classList.remove('hidden'); // Оставляем только кликнутый
    return;
  }
  addClass(block, 'hidden'); // Иначе - скрываем всё.
});

function addClass(elems, className) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].classList.add(className);
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  /* Железобетонно скрыть, не глядя на другие стили */
}

.block {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.open {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<li class="open">111</li>
<div class="hidden block">Текст 111</div>

<li class="open">222</li>
<div class="hidden block">Текст 222</div>

<li class="open">333</li>
<div class="hidden block">Текст 333</div>
```

И менее хитрозапутанный вариант, для ваших id:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if( e.target.id == 'moo' ){ return; }
  document.getElementById('btn').style.display = 'none';
});


btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); 
  // Можно еще так. Останавливает выполнение функции, запущенной при клике на document
});

function toggle(el) {
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none';
}
```

```css
#btn {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px; width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<li id="moo" onclick="toggle(btn)" class="input">Тест</li>

<div id="btn" style="display: none;">
    <table id="шапка"><tr><td>Тест</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень выручили!!!